# mahapps ShowProgressAsync not show the loader asynchronous - WPF (C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, mahapps.metro

I have a problem with mahapps , the ShowProgressAsync method is displayed but does not show the loading pellets in the bottom . I think it is a problem that the rendering remains synchronous .

Can anyone give me a solution ? I struggle to find the problem .

***Xaml:***

```
<controls:MetroWindow x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Clicca" Width="150" Click="Button_Click" Height="50"></Button>
    </Grid>
</controls:MetroWindow>
```

***Codebehind:***

```
using MahApps.Metro.Controls;
using MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
    {
        ProgressDialogController x;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            x = await this.ShowProgressAsync("test","loading", false) as ProgressDialogController;
        }
    }
}
```

They should come out in the bottom of the shot that flow, but remain blocked

Comment: I have the same problem. The indeterminate bar is not visible even when calling x.SetIndeterminate();

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean that you want to set the progressbar as indeterminate? If that's the case, you are missing a method call right after the ShowProgressAsync

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        x = await this.ShowProgressAsync("test", "loading", false) as ProgressDialogController;
        x.SetIndeterminate();
    }
```

If what you want is to show the actual progress, you should use the method `SetProgress` of x to report the progress with values from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Your Working Code should not block the UI thread in order to let the ProgressWindow to display

```
var controller = await this.ShowProgressAsync("Please wait", "Doing Something...");
// Your code here
await controller.CloseAsync();
```

if your code will block the UI Thread, wrap it inside a new task

```
var controller = await this.ShowProgressAsync("Please wait", "Doing Something...")
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    // Your code here
}
await controller.CloseAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Some code that I've been using to bookend async operations is this...

```
var x = await this.ShowProgressAsync("Please wait", "Doing Something...");
// Your Code Here.
await x.CloseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

If you just want it to appear for say 1 second, then you use...

```
var x = await this.ShowProgressAsync("Please wait", "Waiting for 1 second.");
await Task.Delay(1000);
await x.CloseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```